# Grails 1.3.7 plugin compile error

Tags: grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm having a plugin dependency compile problem in a Grails 1.3.7 project.

This project uses a number of plugins including Spring Security core.

When switching from a 2.0.4 (compiler 1.8) project back to this 1.3.7 project (compiler 1.7) in STS 2.9.2, the project now fails to compile with the following errors:

**`The declared package "grails.plugins.springsecurity" does not match the expected package "plugins.springsecurity"`**

I've tried the usual clean / reimport cycle and have also experimented with changing the class path to use both

```
.link_to_grails_plugins/spring-security-core-1.21/src/java (include all)
```

and

```
.link_to_grails_plugins/spring-security-core-1.21/src/java/grails
```

but to no avail!

Has anyone come across this before / got any pointers?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: I'd delete the ~/.grails/1.3.7 folder and let all the dependencies re-cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies from inside STS.

Also, try to run grails compile from the command line.  If this works, but not the former, then there's some problem with the project in STS.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response on this. Deleting the `plugins` and `plugins-classes` directories followed by refreshing dependencies and then a clean worked for a while. However I got the same problem a few hours later so I ended up re-installing STS.